# Replace a string with a new string on a condition

Tags: java, string

I'm making a program where a user inputs name, P, S or T, and number of rounds. It will then check if they are equal, or not (one wins depending on condition of choices? This is a rock, paper, scissors game). And then, if they are equal, I want it to print a replaced version of `iChoice` and `iComputerChoice` in the `JOPtionPane`. (Since in this case, it will only print P, S or T). These are the replacements:

"P" = "Paper" // "S" = "Scissors" // "T" = "Stone"

Below is the code block:

```
if(iComputerchoice.equals(iChoice))
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "Computer: " +iComputerchoice + "\n" + "" +iName + ": " + "" +iChoice + "\nIt's a tie!", "Result", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
        }
```

Example:
iComputerchoice = P
iChoice = P

Computer = Paper // Your Name = Paper // It's a tie!

I know a way to do this but it's kinda long. I'm wondering if there's a shorter way to do this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

in many ways. For instance, write a method that will do the conversion for you:

```
private String convertChoice(String abbr)
{
   if (abbr.equals("T")) return "Stone";
   else if (abbr.equals("S")) return "Scissors";
   else return "Paper";
}
```

then use convertChoice(iChoice) instead of iChoice when updating the value in your JOptionPane.

Comment: if you are using java 8, you can use switch statement (java 8 supports switch for strings). you will be maintaining one string to be returned, which you will return after switch block. This way you will do away with so many return statements, which is not considered good programming.

Answer (score 0):

Well I don't know it's a good/bad way, but was just curious so tried this out , you can use a `HashMap` to write your "keys" and display its value when needed.

```
Map<String,String> map=new HashMap();
  map.put("p","paper");
  map.put("t","Stone");
  map.put("s","Scissor");
```

A demo short example:

```
 Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.println("T-Stone..P-paper..S-Scissors..enter");
   String choice=scan.nextLine().toLowerCase().trim();

   Map<String,String> map=new HashMap();
   map.put("p","paper");
   map.put("t","Stone");
   map.put("s","Scissor");


   //s b p-> scissor beats paper   
     final   String test="s b p , t b s , p b t";
     String vals[]={"p","s","t"};

     String ichoice=vals[new Random().nextInt(3)+0];//((max - min) + 1) + min

     if(ichoice.equalsIgnoreCase(choice)){

         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"  Tie !!--"+map.get(ichoice));
         System.exit(1);
    }

      String match=ichoice+" b "+choice;

     if(test.contains(match))  
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"  CPU Won!!--!"+map.get(ichoice));
     else
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"  YOU Won!!--"+map.get(ichoice));
```